# Creating Discord.js pagination and getting error with 'channel'

Tags: javascript, discord.js

so i'm trying to make pagination of embeds (pages) and I'm having a problem.
TypeError: Cannot read property 'channel' of undefined
I'm kinda still new at Discord.js, any help would be apresuated

```js
client.on('message', async (client, message, args, tools) => {
let pages = ['page one', 'second', 'third', 'you can add pages', 'all you need to do is add another item in the array', '**Supports markdown and regular chat description properties**'];
let page = 1;
const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('red')
    .setFooter(`Page ${page} of ${pages.length}`)
    .setDescription(pages[page-1])
    message.channel.send(embed).then(msg => {
        msg.react('⏮️').then(r => {
            msg.react('⏭️')
            const backwardsFilter = (reaction, user) => reaction.emoji.name === '⏮️' && user.id === message.author.id;
            const forwardsFilter = (reaction, user) => reaction.emoji.name === '⏭️' && user.id === message.author.id;

            const backwards = msg.createReactionCollector(backwardsFilter, { time: 60000 });
            const forwards = msg.createReactionCollector(forwardsFilter, { time: 60000 });

            backwards.on('collect', r => {
                if (page ===1) return;
                page--;
                embed.setDescription(pages[page-1]);
                embed.setFooter(`Page ${page} of ${pages.length}`)
                msg.edit(embed)
            })
            forwards.on('collect', r => {
                if (page === pages.length) return;
                page++;
                embed.setDescription(pages[page-1]);
                embed.setFooter(`Page ${page} of ${pages.length}`);
                msg.edit(embed)
            })
        })
    })
})
```

Comment: The message event only passes the `message` parameter. You can't use `client, args`, or `tools` directly from this event.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!